# Creating neo4j Nodes Dynamically using Neo4jClient

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I have a base class for nodes:

```
public abstract class Node
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string Type { get; }
}
```

And have my other node classes like this

```
public class Item : Node
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string ItemNumber {get; set;}
    public override string Type
   {
        get { return "Item"; }
   }
}
```

There are many other classes like the `Item` class that represent different node types, how would i create a method that you pass the node type in and the method then creates that specific node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) creational pattern.